# Angular 2: Radio button not working as expected

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a table by iterating over items in a shopping cart. For each item, I create a delivery method column of radio buttons that allow the user to select one of three of delivery methods (STORE PICKUP, TRUCK DELIVERY, PARCEL).

The table rows are created, each row has three distinct radio buttons that could be selected. The problem is when a radio button is selected in one row, "STORE PICKUP", for instance, all of the "STORE PICKUP" radio buttons are selected for every row in the table. I expect only the radio "STORE PICKUP" for the the specific row I have chosen to be selected. What am I doing wrong?

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of cartService.cart.items">
      <td class="lgcol">
        <a [routerLink]="['/product', item.product._id]">
            <img src="..\assets\image\{{getDisplayImage(item.product, item.color)}}" >
            <br/><br/>
            <p>{{item.product.name}}</p>
          </a>
        <p>Item #{{item.product.model}}</p>
      </td>
      <td class="lgcol">
        <p *ngFor="let delivery of dataService.deliveryMethods">
            <input type="radio" name="deliveryMethod" [(ngModel)]="item.deliveryMethod"
              [value]="delivery.value">
            {{delivery.label}}
          </p>
        <br>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Cart item class:

```
export class CartItem {
  product: Product;
  quantity: number;
  itemTotal: number;
  color: string;
  protectionPlan: string;
  deliveryMethod: string;
}
```

Deliver Methods:

```
deliveryMethods = [
   { value: 'Store Pickup', label: 'Store Pickup' },
   { value: 'Truck Delivery', label: 'Truck Delivery' },
   { value: 'Parcel Shipping', label: 'Parcel Shipping' },    
 ]
```

Comment: All your radio buttons have the same name. So they're all part of the same group. Give them different names. Complete simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gsywZKHwUTiq7qWwZVsH?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign different `name` attribute for group of radio button of `cart.item`. Since you have same name for all of your radio `input`, they considered as the same.

For solving the issue you could concatenate attribute name with `cart.items` index like `name="deliveryMethod{{i}}"`

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of cartService.cart.items;let i=index;">
    <td class="lgcol">
        <a [routerLink]="['/product', item.product._id]">
          <img src="..\assets\image\{{getDisplayImage(item.product, item.color)}}" >
          <br/><br/>
          <p>{{item.product.name}}</p>
        </a>
        <p>Item #{{item.product.model}}</p>
    </td>
    <td class="lgcol">
        <p *ngFor="let delivery of dataService.deliveryMethods">
            <input type="radio" name="deliveryMethod{{i}}" 
              [(ngModel)]="item.deliveryMethod" [value]="delivery.value" /> 
            {{delivery.label}}
        </p>
        <br>
    </td>
</tr>
```